# Is there a way to edit the VSCode Integrated Terminal to only display the file name when running a file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VsCode Terminal:
[image]

In the first line of the above image you can see there is a bunch of useless fluff that I want to remove. I managed to remove the fluff in the Prompt changing it to just "$" and want to do something similar for the line where the file is executed.

Comment: What do you mean by "running a file". Is it the built-in Run and Debug?

Comment: Yes sorry useing the "Run Python File" button on the top right

Comment: No, this way the python extension is always able to start the debugging no  matter what location the terminal is currently at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the design of VS Code, it uses the built-in powershell of the computer, so you must specify the interpreter and file location used before running the code.

But the advantage of this is that no matter where you are, VS Code can always run the code and debug files correctly.

If you want a clean output, use the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. After installing this extension, the play button in the upper right corner will become three options:

[image]

Select **Run Code**, and the code result will be output in the **OUTPUT** panel.

[image]

Add the following configuration in settings.json, the panel only shows the result.

```json
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `#!/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` to line 1 of `hello.py`
2. `cd /Users/julioguidotti/Documents/Harvard\ CS50P`
3. Make `hello.py` executable (`chmod 755 hello.py` or `chmod +x hello.py`)
4. Run the file `./hello.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be better to use the **Debug Console** instead of the **Terminal** then.

To do this, you need a custom launch configuration:

In the **Run and Debug** tab click **create a launch.json file** (if you don't have one already) and select the **Python File** template. Then, in `.vscode/launch.json` change property `"console": "integratedTerminal",` to `"console": "internalConsole"` for the desired configuration.

Make sure to switch to **Debug Console** tab after you're done (Cmd+Shift+Y on Mac, or click the tab next to your Terminal).

[image]